# Is there a way for me to use regex to distinguish this set of input?

Tags: regex, string-matching

Here is one input

```
<some tag: 1 2 3>
```

Here is another input

```
<some tag: 1 2 3>
  some extra data
</some tag>
```

Both inputs appear in the same string. It looks like this:

```
<some tag: 1 2 3>  
<some tag: 4 5 6>
  some extra data
</some tag>
```

Note: this is not XML parsing. I just happen to like the way XML looks.

These are two separate pieces of information, and I would like to be able to capture them correctly.

The first match should give

- 1 2 3

The second match should give

- 4 5 6
- some extra data

The name of the tag itself is not important; it's just used as an indicator to show that this is the data I'm looking for.

Is it possible to write a regular expression that will capture this correctly?

The regex I'm using is

```
<some tag:(.+?)>(([\s\S]*?)<\/some tag>)?
```

So basically, the first line is required, but everything afterwards is optional.

However, the problem here is when someone mixes the two forms of input: the first match would take this

```
1 2 3
```

But then it would continue and capture everything under it as well, since there exists a "closing" tag at the end. So the actual match is this:

First

```
1 2 3
```

Second

```
<some tag: 4 5 6>
  some extra data
```

My other solution would be to simply make it so that you would write

```
<some tag: 1 2 3 /> 
<some tag: 4 5 6>
  some extra data
</some tag>
```

So that I will have one regex to parse the ones that don't have any extra data, and then another regex to handle the ones that do, but if I could avoid writing in that extra `/` that would be preferable.

I could potentially use a CFG to parse it, but I'd like to be able to just throw a regex at it, but I'm not sure if regex is powerful enough to support it.

Comment: Regular expression will be powerful enough if and only if your tags cannot nest arbitrarily. But even then, I think they will become so complicated that you'd be better off writing a few lines of code in the programming language of your choice to distinguish the cases and only use regular expressions as a lower-level building block.

Comment: What most languages call "regexp" are not actually regular expressions. E.g. Perl 5.12's and Ruby 1.9's regexp can parse non-regular languages, probably even all context-free languages. (Ruby's even have choice and named recursion, I wouldn't be surprised if someday someone got bored enough to prove them Turing-complete.)

Answer (score 2):

If your syntax makes no distinction between an opening tag and a self-closing tag, then you end up with this scenario:

```
<a>
  <a>
    Some text
  </a>
  <b>
    Some more text
  </b>
```

The closing tag of a refers to the first a tag or the 2nd?  Indented like this, my intent is more clear, though you could equally see the following:

```
<a><a>Some text</a><b>Some more text</b>
```

The difficulty arises in how you interpret successive tags.  Is b a root tag or is it under the first a tag?

It *is* your language afterall, and you can choose to interpret it either way, however I personally would prefer to remove ambiguity from the language entirely so that anyone using it would know how it is interpretted.  Adding a slash to indicate a self-closing tag seems like the most logical conclusion that requires minimum effort on the part of someone writing it and has a clear meaning.